# Passing Windows username/password to an app?

Tags: windows-10, security

I log into Windows (and an AD domain) using a username/password which then I need to specify again to Cisco AnyConnect. It'd be so great if I only needed to do this once. Is there a way to reuse the credentials entered?

Answer (score 1):

This question was raised in 2018 at the Cisco Community post
[Single Sign-On with Anyconnect](https://community.cisco.com/t5/vpn/single-sign-on-with-anyconnect/td-p/3738521).

The short answer given by stsargen, a Cisco employee, was:

> AnyConnect VPN does not support SSO using Windows logon credentials.

So unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: If they did, they haven't published it - Cisco products are not made to be easy to hack. A more recent [article](https://community.cisco.com/t5/vpn/anyconnect-authentication-using-logged-on-credentials/td-p/4046707) gives as solution using credentials instead of passwords. See also [ASA AnyConnect Double Authentication with Certificate Validation, Mapping, and Pre-Fill Configuration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/116111-11611-config-double-authen-00.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to actually store credentials for AnyConnect.

A quick workaround could be enabling "Reconnect After Resume" option in AnyConnect Profile Editor. This is an option of Auto Reconnect feature, when both are enabled your AnyConnect client will attempt reconnection after stand-by/hibernation, brief network loss or connection switches between WiFis, etc.
This can saves you much of the typework at the end of the day.

According to official Cisco [AnyConnect Client Administrator guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect40/administration/guide/b_AnyConnect_Administrator_Guide_4-0/configure-vpn.html) you can achieve this by the following:

```
Step 1
  Open the VPN Profile Editor and choose Preferences (Part 1) from the navigation pane.

Step 2  
  Select Auto Reconnect.

Step 3  
  Choose the Auto Reconnect Behavior:

 - Disconnect On Suspend—(Default) AnyConnect releases the resources assigned to the VPN session upon a system suspend and does not attempt to reconnect after the system resume.
 - Reconnect After Resume—The client retains resources assigned to the VPN session during a system suspend and attempts to reconnect after the system resume.
```

Alternatively, you could generate a simple script to automate login using AnyConnect `vpncli.exe` program, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682121/cisco-vpn-client-automatic-login).
Anyway, i wouldn't advise this solution as it involves storing your domain credentials in clear-text, which is never a good idea imho.

Password-less authentication on AnyConnect client is possible, but requires server side configuration, such as CA certificate authentication either via LocalCA on Cisco ASA or a dedicated CA server.